# Redirect subdomain.example.com to example.com in firebase web hosting, but keep the URL intact

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I have hosted https://example.com on firebase web hosting

Now, I would like https://subdomain.example.com to go the https://example.com hosted site, but URL should be intact and still show https://subdomain.example.com.

I will handle the UI on Web Pages based on the subdomain name and hence retaining subdomain is very important.

If I use 'redirect to existing domain' option, then URL is changed. Is there any configuration which allows me to do this on firebase?

Website is built using AngularIO, so any suggestion as part of Angular deployment is also welcome.

While there are similar questions on the site, I couldn't find any solution. So, asking here again with more clear description. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Just connect `subdomain.example.com` but don't set it as a redirect. All domains/subdomains connected to a project that are not redirects will resolve the same content.